# Ошибка в Magento

Tags: php, magento, controller

Только сделал свой первый модуль на `Magento2` и хочу перейти на `action` контроллера `helloworld/index/index/`, но сразу выбрасывает ошибку:

> Notice: Undefined index: modules in
>   /.../.../.../magento2.test/vendor/magento/framework/App/Route/Config/Converter.php
>   on line 47

Кеш почистел, индексы обновил но ошибка осталась.

**Как это исправить ?**

Comment: в конфиге модуля надо смотреть что там.

Comment: @Naumov, разобрался. Просто  переставил через composer  і все решилось

Comment: Вроде пилил проэкт на 1.9 теперь на 2-ю перейти решил? :D

Comment: @Naumov, вообще ни разу не работал с magento, пришел на роботу и бос сразу сказал модуль на 1,9 сделать. Сдал, кинул ему) ну и чтоб без дела не сидел дали задание на 2-ю )

Comment: Да знакомая история я когда начинал так же было. Сейчас только с ней в основном и работаю... Узкая специализация, правда вторую пощупал немного но пока сыровата для меня. Да и многие не умеют работать с ней, нахватали заказов а грамотно реализовать не могут, по этому пока отказываюсь от неё.

Comment: @Naumov, вернули  доработать модуль! Если можно подскажите как реализовать, чтоб по ссылке можно было переходить только если был сделан вход в аккаунт (пользователя). Понимаю что нужно копать в сторону ролей и тд. но конкретно не знаю как .

Comment: В админке или на фронте?

Comment: @Naumov, на фронте !

Comment: Так на фронте нет ролей, вставь просто if'ы в шаблонах `if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){...ссылка...}` и в контроллерах в начале `if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){... redirect ...}` хотя в controller можно переопределить метод `_isAvailable()` точно название не помню, надо посмотреть в abstract классе, если в нём возвращаеться true то контроллер доступен если фалсе то нет.

Comment: @Naumov, спасибо ) так и сделал !

Comment: Пожалуйста, часто сдесь бываю так что всегда рад помочь, особенно с magento.

Comment: @Naumov, как раз с magento сейчас и нужна помощь )